# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header Authentication Issue

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, oauth

I was trying to call OAuth from our website but it gives an error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://****.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' from origin
> 'https://*******.com.ph' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

And i already added this on COR Policy
[image]

here is the Javascript im Using

```
jQuery.ajax({
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://***.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
        data: {
             "client_id":"****",
        "client_secret":"****",
        "username":"*****",
        "password":"*****",
        "grant_type":"password",
        },
        
        success: function (response) {
            //service.php response
            console.log(response);
            // jQuery("#form-field-uthentication_token").val(response.access_token);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, did you resolve it ? I am facing the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add your site into below:

1. CSP Trusted Sites
2. CORS Setting

In addition to the above, did you try using ConnectedApp to achieve what you wanted?

Also i had used Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin chrome extension to test.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I did try.. still the same.... :(